# Tomcat 8.0.x Websockets, SSL and Windows --> last frame delayed

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, websocket, internet-explorer-11

1/ 
Install the latest version of tomcat (8.0.28) and run it on java 8 (I'm using the 1.8.0_45 / 64-Bit version).
I'm running the Tomcat on a Windows 7 64-Bit

2/ Enable SSL on Tomcat:
 Activate SSL by creating a keystore and uncommenting the https connector in the server.xml file, add
    keystoreFile="" keystorePass="" 
    to the connector.
FYI: here is my connector:

```
   <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"  
               keystorePass="password" 
               keystoreFile="/path/to/my/keystore" />
```

3/ Install Fiddler (www.telerik.com/fiddler) or any other tool to sniff the traffic between your host and the server, the fiddler should run on your host. I did my screen shots with Fiddler.

4/ 
Go to tools/options/https and check "enable decrypt".

5/ 
Using Internet explorer 11 (chrome also works but as it compresses the websocket traffic it makes it harder to reach 8KB of data), access your tomcat remotely using https and open the example app at https://server:8443/examples/websocket/echo.xhtml

choose "Programmatic API", hit "Connect", then send a small test message

on fiddler, double click on the websocket session and look at the result in the websocket tab.

Now, try to send a large text of say 20KB, you'll see that the reply is split in frames of 8KB marked "Continuation". There should be a frame marked "Final" which is missing at this point.

Send another small message so that the missing frame is flushed.

## Important:

If I connect to a Tomcat running locally on my host I do not reproduce this issue.
If I do not use SSL, I do not reproduce this issue.

Questions: 
- why such behavior, did anyone experience the same thing ?
- how to properly troubleshoot this issue ?
- I tried to enable the Tomcat logging but nothing interesting in the logging: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.level = FINE

The issue is apparently OS related:
When Tomcat is on Windows 7 it does not work
When Tomcat is on Windows 10 it works
When Tomcat is on Windows Server 2012 R2 it works

In short this issue a combination of OS (some versions of windows) / SSL and WebSockets.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "dirty" workaround I found for now is to send a last message to flush the buffer since I have access to the code of the server side.

please let me knwo if you faced such issue as this could be something related to the SSL handshake for some specific windows versions and I don't knwo how to trouble shoot that.